# 403 forbidden on accessing IPV4 address for ec2 app

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, psql

I have a rails application hosted on `ec2` and my db is `psql`.

I stopped my instance earlier to connect it to a different `volume` and then reconnected it to the original volume. But now navigating to the `IPV4` address for the EC2 instance throws a:

`403 Forbidden nginx/1.10.1`

Is there a way to fix this?

My logs for `psql` are as follows:

[image]

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: @kichik I added my psql logs